# python: Plotting and optimizing the same function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Lets say I have the following function:

```
def f(x):
    return log(3*exp(3*x) + 7*exp(7*x))
```

I want to do two things:

1) plot the function over a range of x-values

2) find the root of the function using the Newton method from scipy

My problem is that it seems that plotting is best done with a numpy array `x=np.linspace(-2,2,1000)`, but then evaluating the function results in erros `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. I can fix this by simply changing `log` and `exp` to `np.log` and `np.exp`, respectively.

But doing so then makes scipy.optimize.newton unhappy.

It seems like I need to define the function twice, once for use in plotting (with `np. ...`) and once for optimizing in the form given above.

I can't imagine that this is actually the case. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce when defining function with `np.exp` and `np.log`.  `newton(f, x0=0)` finds a root at -0.468...   (scipy == 1.4.1)

Comment: @DouglasJamesBock What's your scipy version? (`pip freeze | grep scipy`) will tell you

Comment: Hmm, possibly your scipy is borked? Try uninstalling and reinstalling. If the problem persists, maybe paste the full code you use and stacktrace you get when calling the scipy.optimize.root function?

Answer (score 0):

Seems legit, you just need to use numpy functions instead of base math functions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def f(x):
  return np.log(3*np.exp(3*x) + 7*np.exp(7*x))

x = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
y = f(x) 
plt.scatter(x, y)

optimize.root(f, 1)
```

Comment: mmmmh... but doing that gives me a `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`. If I skip the optimisation though, the plot appears, so it is not an error in my formatting of the function...

Comment: Hmm, are you running just the code above? If not, can you print(x) and validate its a numpy array? (You should call `f` on the full array, not on each member of `x`. This keeps the math "vectorized" and fast.) Paste the full code you're using, and only the code you're using, along with the stacktrace and we'll get this sorted...